# Plotting isoclines

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The problem:

> Given a map $f(x,y)$, a rectangle $R=[x_1,x_2]\times [y_1,y_2]$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$ plot the isocline $\{(x,y)\in R:f(x,y)=c\}$.

With plot I mean a list (since the isocline needs not to be connected, in any case in the given rectangle) of list of points whose distance is less than some given $\delta>0$.

A brute-force method would be to evaluate $f$ on a grid (lets start with 10x10) and then select all the segments (vertical or horizontal) where the values are one greater and one lesser than $c$; then consider the two small rectangles adjacent to the segment(s) and split them into 4 parts (a 2D bisection method). In some cases one has to add back some adjacent rectangle; but lets forget about it.

I think that the described method should work.
Is there some standard method to solve this problem? 
Perhaps with a name that I can lookup for?
I'm not looking for a library, but a principle/algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

All software that plots implicit functions does something like this.  The help file for the Maple command [implicitplot](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/helpJP/Maple/view.aspx?path=plots%2fimplicitplot) has some description of what it does.